# Is there a nice way to "null" a member variable when returning the value from a method?

Tags: java

I have some code that looks like this, in order to ensure that Foo doesn't hold
on to a reference it no longer needs:

```
class Foo {
  T field;

  T method()
  {

     ....

     T tmp = field;
     field = null;
     return tmp;
  }
}
```

This looks rather ugly. Is there any more pleasant way to take out the garbage?

Comment: Can you refactor so that you don't need to ever hold a `T` reference?

Comment: It seems messy to have `T field` .. (also, I changed the title wording and tags to avoid tangent GC answers, I trust you need to "null" for whatever reason you have)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I don't think so, no. It's a value that the object will acquire sometimes, and once it has it it needs to hang on until it's time to use it, after which it's not needed and should be scrapped.

Comment: @user2864740, do you have another suggestion? I thought about using an Optional, but that doesn't support nulls, and although I found a Maybe on github, I'm not entirely sure it's implemented right.

Comment: @dfeuer Not without knowing the entire context - it might be required to be structured like that, but I rarely need such a construct.

Comment: What is "ugly" about the above??

Comment: I think maybe you could write your own generic class so that you could could declare `OneTimeFieldContainer<T> field;` and then `return field.getAndNull();` in your method.  Whether that's more trouble than it's worth, I don't know.  That might be uglier than what you already wrote.

Comment: @user2864740 Context: I'm implementing a simple class representing the "intersection" of two Iterators of elements that can be compared with a Comparator. In order to perform hasNext() it needs to step the Iterators until it finds a matching pair, but then it needs to hold on to that value so it's available for the next call to next().

Comment: You can use try/finally but I think it looks worse.

Comment: @McDowell, that sounds awful, but what would it look like?

Comment: `try { return field; } finally { field = null; }`

Comment: @McDowell Why is that even allowed????

Comment: _finally_ blocks are for clean-up. For better or worse, this counts.

Comment: @dfeur finally is part of a contract, meaning that it will ALWAYS execute, even if exceptions or returns break the control flow. It is a good thing ;-)

Comment: I think your approach belies a fundamental problem, you seem to assume user will call `hasNext()` before `next()`.  This isn't part of the contract with Iterator interface.  `mySet.iterator().next()` is somewhat common coding for retrieving an arbitrary member from a known non-empty set, for example.

Comment: @Taylor, actually, `hasNext` and `next` both use a helper method `step`. `step` ensures that either the `done` flag is set or `field` has something stored in it and the `fieldValid` flag is set. But `next` invalidates `field`, and therefore should throw it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a try-finally block

```
class Foo {
  T field;

  T method()
  {
     ....
     try {
       ....
       return field;
     } finally {
       field = null;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have changed 3 lines into 5.  Is that really a more "pleasant" solution?

Comment: @StephenC It does make it a bit clearer that setting `field` to `null` is a cleanup operation, rather than something inherent to the correct functioning of the method.

Comment: I would prefer this solution, I would assume the code is much more complex. Thus, this solution assures, that field is indeed set to null, even if the control flow could go somewhere else (maybe a second return, maybe exceptions...). Number of lines usually is not the only criterion for pleasant code.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - that interpretation is entirely in the eye of the beholder :-)

Comment: I eliminated an unnecessary temporary variable which makes it more pleasant for me. The beauty of code is not always in fewer lines :)

Comment: @Dero - actually, the try/finally version is NOT equivalent to the original code because `field` is going to be nulled irrespective of whether the value is returned.  It is only truly equivalent if you delete the 2nd "....".

Comment: @StephenC But hopefully, the only thing inside the `try` block is the `return field;` .  The rest of the code should be before it, just like in the original.

Comment: @StephenC If you want to clear the `field` only in case you hit this specific `return` then just put the try-finally around this specific `return`. Which makes this solution 100% equivalent to the original code.

Comment: As an aside, in Common Lisp there's are `prog1` and `prog2` blocks that evaluate any number of expression, but return the value of the first or second, respectively.  I find this use of try/finally similar to those (with the exception, of course, that the exception handling is different).

Comment: Accepted. I think I'm going to stick with my original solution, but this is the most interesting/useful alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any more pleasant way to take out the garbage?

The short answer is no.

You could possibly do something using reflection (e.g. a helper method that takes the *name* of the field as a parameter, etcetera), allowing you to express the method body in one line.  But that's NOT what I would call pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

Some setter methods return the previous value of the thing being set.  For instance, [Map.put(key,value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) returns the previous value associated with the key.  You might use that idiom to finish your method with:

```
return setField( null );
```

to both set the field to `null`, and to return its (prior) value.  This is certainly a little bit shorter: it turns three lines into one (at the cost of moving them someplace else, but that's not so much of a concern).  Whether this is clearer or not, though, depends on whether your codebase makes much use of the "return the previous value" idiom.  If you're not using it elsewhere, then this code isn't very clear (but you can add a comment, of course).  If you use this idiom here, and you're using a "return the new value" idiom elsewhere (e.g., for method chaining), then this become very opaque.

Aside from those issues of clarity, it's also worth noting that this does violate the typical convention and JavaBeans "protocol" of setters being `void` methods.  It also becomes a bit hairy if you have lots of these kinds of fields, as you start to need such a method for each one.

Your code would be like this:

```
class Foo {
  T field;

  T method() {
     ....
     return setField( null );
  }

  T setField( T value ) {
    T old = field;
    field = value;
    return old;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this are that you need to declare a `setField` method for each field.  Besides, this violates the JavaBeans "protocol" which requires / assumes setters to be `void` methods.

Comment: @StephenC Valid points;  I've updated the answer to include them.  I'm not crazy about this solution, personally.  Rather than `void` methods, I'd rather that setter methods returned the new value.  In my opinion, that behavior would be more consistent with the fact that the value of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned.